# Converting datetime to a custom format

Tags: c#, datetime, unity-game-engine

I am trying to convert a datetime which is in the format with a timezone to a specified custom format with only date and time. I am able to convert it but the result is shown completely different. For example:

```
string dateTime = Convert.ToDateTime ("2020-08-25T23:55:00+00:00").ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
Debug.Log (dateTime);
```

The result in the log I get is : 2020-08-26 01:55

It shows result as the next day with totally additionally 2 hours time. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: @DragandDrop Can the timezone not affect the date-time I am converting it to? My only motive is to display the date and time entered as it is. The result here should be 2020-08-25 23:55.

Comment: You are specifying a time that is in the GMT/UTS time zone (with the `+00:00`) on a date that is in daylight savings time in that region. Your local time is presumably 1 hour ahead of UTC, plus the DST gives 2 hours ahead. If you don't want it to account for the time zone, don't specify a time zone.

Comment: @MatthewWatson unfortunately it is not upto me to "not specify a timezone". As I am importing this structure of datetime from the server, I need to display the date-time in the custom format without considering the timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is because of your Timezone. That's why you have different datetime after conversion. Try to use Parse instead of Convert method.

```
using System.Globalization;

var dateTime = DateTime.Parse ("2020-08-25T23:55:00+00:00", null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal).ToString ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");;
Debug.Log (dateTime);
```

Comment: use the library "using System.Globalization;" on the top of the file or just change  "DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal" to --> "System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal